# Structured Logging with Application Insights for Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, azure-application-insights

Does anyone know how to configure structured logging for Application Insights from Microsoft Azure working with a Spring Boot app?

It works for json logging to the consol but not for log analytics in Application Insights.

Answer (score 0):

You could log to Log Analytics. There is a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/publish-springboot-logs-to-azure-log-analytics) on how to achieve that. You could connect log analytics and application insights, as they are anyway heavily connected. For details see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource)